# Magento 2 | Exclude Video from fotoroma fullscreen gallery on PDP

Tags: magento2, product-page, gallery, pdp, fotoroma

I want to remove video from gallery when fullscreen gallery is opened on PDP. on normal gallery video is required but need to remove only on fullscreen.

fotoroma using same data for gallery and fullscreen gallery.

is there any way to achieve this??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When the gallery is open to fullscreen the class "fotorama--fullscreen" is added to the div.

You can use javascript to hide the video div class="fotorama-video-container" when you click on the fotorama

Edit :

Check the file : vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/frontend/web/js/fotorama-add-video-events.js

On line 246, the function :

```
        _listenForFullscreen: function () {
            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:fullscreenenter.' + this.PV, $.proxy(function () {
                this.isFullscreen = true;
                // My edit
                for (let i = 0;i <= this.defaultVideoData.length; i++){
                    if (this.defaultVideoData[i].mediaType === 'external-video'){
                        $('.video-thumb-icon').hide();
                    }
                }
                //Edit End
            }, this));

            this.fotoramaItem.on('fotorama:fullscreenexit.' + this.PV, $.proxy(function () {
                this.isFullscreen = false;
                this._hideVideoArrows();
                $('.video-thumb-icon').show();
            }, this));
        },
```

Maybe add more mediaType check if the video is internal, i tried with a vimeo link and it works.

Not the cleanest way, you sould override the file in your theme.

Comment: Thanks for answer I tried this already but when we click on next slide it's become visible again

Comment: This jquery way never work properly. Is there anyway with fotoroma library??

Comment: check my update answer

Comment: after entering full screen have you clicked on next slide if you have 3 images and 1 video, and if you click or change image then video will again show.

Comment: BTW thanks for your efforts